# Fujita's ampleness conjecture for very ample line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$; $\mathcal A$ a *very ample* invertible $\mathcal O_X$-module. I know that $\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal A^{\otimes d}$ (instead of $\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal A^{\otimes d + 1}$) is generated by global sections unless $(X, \mathcal A) = (\mathbf P^d, \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^d}(1))$ (see, for example, Karen Smith's *A tight closure proof of Fujita's freeness conjecture for very ample line bundles*) . So I wonder whether it is true that $\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal A^{\otimes d + 1}$ (instead of $\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal A^{\otimes d + 2}$) is very ample unless $(X, \mathcal A) = (\mathbf P^d, \mathcal O_{\mathbf P^d}(1))$?

Comment: The Segre product variety construction shows that the tensor product of a globally generated invertible sheaf and a very ample invertible sheaf is again a very ample invertible sheaf.